# What is the best way to get a list of nodes that belong to a Cassandra cluster?

Tags: scripting, cassandra, nodetool

I'm creating some scripts for some Cassandra clusters I operate.  Some of these scripts need a list of nodes that are part of the cluster.

`nodetool status` will print a list of the nodes and their current state, but it prints out more information than I need.  For example:

```
$ nodetool status mykeyspace
Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address      Load       Tokens  Owns    Host ID                               Rack
UN  10.11.12.13  47.66 KB   1       33.3%   aaa1b7c1-6049-4a08-ad3e-3697a0e30e10  rack1
UN  10.11.12.14  47.67 KB   1       33.3%   1848c369-4306-4874-afdf-5c1e95b8732e  rack1
UN  10.11.12.15  47.67 KB   1       33.3%   49578bf1-728f-438d-b1c1-d8dd644b6f7f  rack1
```

The list of the nodes should be IPs only ( hostnames aren't necessary) and I'd like clean output like the following:

```
10.11.12.13
10.11.12.14
10.11.12.15
```

What is the best/simplest way to do this?

<sup>I'll provide my current method below for doing this, but if there's a better way I'd love to see it.  Even if it doesn't use the `nodetool` command.</sup>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `nodetool status` command with `awk`:

```
nodetool status | awk '/^(U|D)(N|L|J|M)/{print $2}'
```

Each line that contains information about a node will either start with the Status of the node being **U**p or **D**own ( `^(U|N)` ) followed by the State of the node being **N**ormal, **L**eaving, **J**oining, or **M**oving ( `(N|L|J|M)` ).

Just so long as the Apache Cassandra developers don't change the output of the `nodetool status` command this should work fine.